# Flutter (\t) string values alignment issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to display the below map data in the flutter widget.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = {
    "1335": "\t     \tE      \t     \t          \t",
    "1336": "\t     \tEG     \t     \t          \t",
    "1337": "\t     \tEFG    \t     \t          \t",
    "1338": "\t     \tEFG    \t     \t          \t",
    "1339": "\t     \tADEFGH \t     \t          \t",
    "1340": "\t     \tADEGHI \t     \t          \t",
    "1341": "\t     \tADEGHI \t     \t          \t",
    "1342": "\t     \tADHIJLM\t     \t          \tK",
    "1343": "\t     \tADIJKL \t     \tI         \tK",
    "1344": "\t     \tBCDJKL \t     \tBCFGIJK   \tK",
    "1345": "\t     \tBCK    \t     \tABCEFGHIJK\tK",
    "1346": "\t     \tK      \tA    \tABCDEHIJK \tJKL",
    "1347": "\t     \t       \tA    \tADEIK     \tJKL",
    "1348": "\t     \t       \tAB   \tADK       \tJKL",
    "1349": "\t     \t       \tBD   \tAK        \tJL",
    "1350": "\t     \t       \tCDGH \tAK        \tJL",
    "1351": "\t     \t       \tDEFGH\tAKL       \tJLM",
    "1352": "\t     \t       \tEFI  \tLM        \tAJLM",
    "1353": "\t     \t       \tI    \tL         \tAJ",
    "1354": "\t     \t       \tIJ   \t          \tAIJ",
    "1355": "\t     \t       \tJL   \t          \tAEIJ",
    "1356": "\t     \t       \tJKLM \t          \tABEFIJ",
    "1357": "\t     \t       \tKLM  \t          \tABCDEFGHI",
    "1358": "\t     \t       \t     \t          \tCDGH",
    "1359": "\t     \t       \t     \t          \tG",
    "1360.0": "\t08/20\t09/20  \t10/20\t11/20     \t12/20"
  };
```

I have used Wrap widget with vertical direction to render this data.

```
return Wrap(
      runSpacing: 30,
      spacing: 2.0,
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
      children: map1.entries
          .map(
            (e) => Text(
              e.key + ':' + e.value,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              textScaleFactor: 1,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                wordSpacing: 5,
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
```

[image: Output]

A to M characters are overlapping with previous rows data. Please help someone to fix this issue.

Comment: Is the Output image in your question your expected output?

Comment: Currently I am getting the attached output message, which is not aligned correctly. 11/20, 12/20 is not aligned as 09/20

Comment: Is this your expected output https://i.imgur.com/2gExGvX.png ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Please find the expected output: https://imgur.com/a/h8yBi16

Comment: Hi bluenile, did you get a chance to look this issue?

Comment: Hi - I did try a few variations, monospaced fonts worked the best. I also found the output is much better on web but on mobile devices the output differs. I try again today and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the following code. I'm using Table instead of Wrap since it gives more control. You may directly run the code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/272875acceeac3a6af5eceb8f65383fa) here https://dartpad.dev/272875acceeac3a6af5eceb8f65383fa

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Flutter Demo")),
        body: Center(child: MyWidget()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, String> map1 = {
      "1335": "\t     \tE      \t     \t          \t",
      "1336": "\t     \tEG     \t     \t          \t",
      "1337": "\t     \tEFG    \t     \t          \t",
      "1338": "\t     \tEFG    \t     \t          \t",
      "1339": "\t     \tADEFGH \t     \t          \t",
      "1340": "\t     \tADEGHI \t     \t          \t",
      "1341": "\t     \tADEGHI \t     \t          \t",
      "1342": "\t     \tADHIJLM\t     \t          \tK",
      "1343": "\t     \tADIJKL \t     \tI         \tK",
      "1344": "\t     \tBCDJKL \t     \tBCFGIJK   \tK",
      "1345": "\t     \tBCK    \t     \tABCEFGHIJK\tK",
      "1346": "\t     \tK      \tA    \tABCDEHIJK \tJKL",
      "1347": "\t     \t       \tA    \tADEIK     \tJKL",
      "1348": "\t     \t       \tAB   \tADK       \tJKL",
      "1349": "\t     \t       \tBD   \tAK        \tJL",
      "1350": "\t     \t       \tCDGH \tAK        \tJL",
      "1351": "\t     \t       \tDEFGH\tAKL       \tJLM",
      "1352": "\t     \t       \tEFI  \tLM        \tAJLM",
      "1353": "\t     \t       \tI    \tL         \tAJ",
      "1354": "\t     \t       \tIJ   \t          \tAIJ",
      "1355": "\t     \t       \tJL   \t          \tAEIJ",
      "1356": "\t     \t       \tJKLM \t          \tABEFIJ",
      "1357": "\t     \t       \tKLM  \t          \tABCDEFGHI",
      "1358": "\t     \t       \t     \t          \tCDGH",
      "1359": "\t     \t       \t     \t          \tG",
      "1360.0": "\t08/20\t09/20  \t10/20\t11/20     \t12/20"
    };

    final List<TableRow> children = (map1.entries.toList().reversed.map((e) {
      return TableRow(children: [
        TableCell(child: Text(e.key)),
        ...e.value
            .split("\t")
            .map(
              (e) => TableCell(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                    child: Text(
                      e.replaceAll(" ", ""),
                      textScaleFactor: 1,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                          wordSpacing: 5,
                          fontFeatures: [FontFeature.tabularFigures()]),
                    )),
              ),
            )
            .toList()
      ]);
    }).toList());

    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Table(
          defaultColumnWidth: const IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
          children: children,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```